# NSIS Scripting Condidtional Section / SectionGroup

Tags: nsis

Apparently, I can't find any help on this. I have a scenario where I want to check if the user has a certain version of the .NET Framework installed on his or her machine. If not, I want to display a mandetory section inside a section-group that let's the user know that a particular version of the .NET Framework is a prerequisite and it will be installed prior to installing the application. How can I go about doing something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Outfile "test.exe"
Requestexecutionlevel user

!include Sections.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Components MyCompPreCallback
Page Instfiles


SectionGroup /e Foo

Section ".NET Framework vX.Y" SEC_DOTNET
SectionIn RO
;File ...
SectionEnd

SectionGroupEnd


Function MyCompPreCallback

StrCpy $0 1 ;TODO: Check if .net is installed and put result in $0

${If} $0 <> 0
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SEC_DOTNET}
${EndIf}

FunctionEnd
```

You can find information about finding the installed version of .NET on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/06/16/9763379.aspx) and by searching the [nsis wiki](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=013152803417979916569%3aziywxtw6b6m&cof=FORID:0&q=net+framework&sa=Search)